# PANDAS merge content of multiple cells wrt to an index

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have this kind of problem.

let's say I have a csv. file like this one

```
           place  X_UTM      Y_UTM           Value_measured
0            A  686439.00  5231330.00             x
1            A  686439.00  5231330.00             y
2            A  686439.00  5231330.00             z
3            A  686439.00  5231330.00             k
4            A  686439.00  5231330.00             j
5            B  790277.00  5192864.00             x'
6            B  790277.00  5192864.00             y'
7            B  790277.00  5192864.00             z'
8            B  790277.00  5192864.00             k'
9            B  790277.00  5192864.00             j'
10           C  600163.00  5204188.00             x"
11           C  600163.00  5204188.00             y"
```

where the columns `place` and `Value_measured` contain string values.

using the following lines:

```
>>test_set_index= place.set_index(['place', 'X_UTM','Y_UTM','Value_measured'])
>>test_set_index
```

output:

```
           place  X_UTM      Y_UTM           Value_measured
0            A  686439.00  5231330.00             x
                                                  y
                                                  z
                                                  k
                                                  j
5            B  790277.00  5192864.00             x'
                                                  y'
                                                  z'
                                                  k'
                                                  j'
10           C  600163.00  5204188.00             x"
                                                  y"
```

what I would like to have is something like this:

```
           place  X_UTM      Y_UTM           Value_measured
0            A  686439.00 5231330.00          x,y,z,k,j
5            B  790277.00 5192864.00          x',y',z',k',j'            
10           C  600163.00  5204188.00         x",y"
```

I would like to merge all the values in the `Value_measured` col with respect to the place and coordinates.

I tried a lot of approaches but I was not able to find something really working. I hope I'm clear.

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html)?

```
In [60]: df.pivot_table(index=['place', 'X_UTM', 'Y_UTM'], aggfunc=lambda x: ','.join(x))
Out[60]:
                           Value_measured
place X_UTM  Y_UTM
A     686439 5231330            x,y,z,k,j
B     790277 5192864  'x','y','z','k','j'
C     600163 5204188              'x','y'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) function `join`. Last you can [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
   place   X_UTM    Y_UTM Value_measured
0      A  686439  5231330              x
1      A  686439  5231330              y
2      A  686439  5231330              z
3      A  686439  5231330              k
4      A  686439  5231330              j
5      B  790277  5192864            'x'
6      B  790277  5192864            'y'
7      B  790277  5192864            'z'
8      B  790277  5192864            'k'
9      B  790277  5192864            'j'
10     C  600163  5204188            'x'
11     C  600163  5204188            'y
```

```
print df.groupby(['place','X_UTM','Y_UTM'])['Value_measured'].apply(",".join).reset_index()

  place   X_UTM    Y_UTM       Value_measured
0     A  686439  5231330            x,y,z,k,j
1     B  790277  5192864  'x','y','z','k','j'
2     C  600163  5204188              'x','y'
```

If you have set index from columns `place`, `X_UTM`, `Y_UTM`:

```
                     Value_measured
place X_UTM  Y_UTM                 
A     686439 5231330              x
             5231330              y
             5231330              z
             5231330              k
             5231330              j
B     790277 5192864            'x'
             5192864            'y'
             5192864            'z'
             5192864            'k'
             5192864            'j'
C     600163 5204188            'x'
             5204188            'y'
```

use `level` in [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
print df.groupby(level=[0,1,2])['Value_measured'].apply(",".join).reset_index()

  place   X_UTM    Y_UTM       Value_measured
0     A  686439  5231330            x,y,z,k,j
1     B  790277  5192864  'x','y','z','k','j'
2     C  600163  5204188              'x','y'
```